# How to Bulk delete messages OLDER THAN 14 DAYS? py-cord

Tags: python, pycord

I am trying to delete all my messages from a Server  (Up to 2 years Old) but I can't Delete older than 14 days (API restriction). To counter that I got IDs of all the messages I ever sent and tried fetching each message object and deleting it one by one. This way works but I hit API limit after every 30 messages deleted.

Here is snippet of what I am trying to do right now.

```
    count=0
    file = open("ids.txt").readlines()  #Reads IDs from a Text file
    channel= await bot.fetch_channel(Channel_ID_OF_SERVER)
    for id in file:
        
        try:
            msg=await channel.fetch_message(id)
        except Exception as e:  
            print(e)
            continue    

        await msg.delete()
        count=count+1
        print("\nDeleted",count,"messages")
```

logging the Above Code got me this error

**2022-07-11 22:16:09,643:DEBUG:discord.http: A rate limit bucket has been exhausted (bucket: 370277460735950852:None:/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message_id}, retry: 86.454).**

This Time limit keeps on increasing.

PS: I have BOT in the server with Message Delete Perm.

Comment: Get an admin ban-unban you.

Comment: @tevemadar Can you please clarify what you are trying to say? I don't understand.

Comment: When a user is banned from a discord server, it's possible to remove all their messages.

Comment: @tevemadar I would like to avoid getting banned. Also I don't want others to know about this till after I am done.